# Separating even and odd numbers in different arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a question for my assignment and this is what it's asking for:
Write a program to separate odd and even integers in separate arrays.
I got the part where you input whatever numbers, but when i run it.. there's an error with the for loops where i try storing the even and odds in separate arrays. 
We just started learning arrays(c#) this week and since the whole virus, we have been doing online class and it's just a lot more difficult. Thanks!

This is the error i got:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException

for this line: 
 odds[y] = i;

So far this is what I have:

```
// Program that seperates odd and even integers -
        int[] nums = new int[10];
        int[] odds = new int[] { };
        int[] evens = new int[] { };
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter 10 integers..\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"Integer[{i}]: ");
            nums[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                evens[x] = i;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                odds[y] = i;
                y++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nEven numbers..\n");
        foreach (int even in evens)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(even);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nOdd numbers..\n");
        foreach (int odd in odds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odd);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please include the text of the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues going on here, but to get over exception you're asking about, you need to initialize your `evens` and `odds` arrays with a size (currently zero).  Since they could potentially be size 10, try that first -

```
 int[] odds = new int[10];
 int[] evens = new int[10];
```

Another hint - after that you are assigning the index of the number to the value in `evens` and `odds`.  It looks like you want to assign the user inputted value instead - `evens[x] = nums[i];`

There's definitely more optimizations you can make, but it sounds like you may be required to use arrays here, so I don't want to start guessing at the rules of the assignment.